# First convert doc, docx , xls, xlsx, ppt, pptx file to pdf in java and open it in browser

Tags: java

I have public URL of an office file, i want to convert it in pdf and then open that file in browser.

how can i do this in Java?

I have a solution for this but it is not specific towards my problem because controlled will not remain in my hand in that case. The solution is that pass that public URL to office online viewer provided by Microsoft and they will open your file in browser. but i need fully control on it like design, new version upload, downloading etc etc

Comment: You might want to look at [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/), which is an open source API for handling various MS Office document types.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that word files are not an open standard, so it's hard to open them.

You will need to use a third party library to decode the document into whatever format you want to use and then use that decoded document.

For example OpenOffice provides an API to do this, it does require an OpenOffice installation and a fair amount of setting up though.

There is also ApachePOI and a few other similar libraries. Each one has its own strengths and weaknesses though so you'll need to evaluate them to find what you need.

Comment: Already i am using an applet which open the file and provide facility to edit as well, but for that applet MS Office installation is necessarily installed on PC, if we are on Mac or Linux machine it definitely will not work. same case for openOffice.

Comment: Hi @Tim B, Is there any way to create macro from terminal of ubuntu OS not from openoffice GUI?

Comment: @Rahul_Dabhi No idea, maybe. Check the open office docs.